# How to hide / remove duplicated Woocommerce products from Shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

a simple question. I'm trying to hide / remove duplicated Woocommerce products on our Shop page. You can have a look here www.nottinghamburger.co.uk/order.Use ng as the postcode.

I'd like to remove the products below the AJAX element

Some help would be much appreciated

Comment: This looks like a template issue.. How are you handling your shop page? Is it a static php page? Are you adding any content from Dashboard->Pages?

Comment: It's a static php page. The page is assigned as the Shop page in Woocommerce settings and therefore shows all products. However I'm using a plugin to display the products in AJAX form, which I want to keep. I want to either hide or remove the products Woocommerce displays on the Shop page.

Comment: Just remove the loop part and keep the content. If this doesn't match your configuration, please share your shop page source code.